# Convert JSON data into an instance of a Django model

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I need to convert JSON data to django model.

This is my JSON data

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "20ad5d9c-b32e-4599-8866-a3aaa5ac77de",
      "name": "name_1"
    },
    {
      "id": "7b6d76cc-86cd-40f8-be90-af6ced7fec44",
      "name": "name_2"
    },
    {
      "id": "b8843b1a-9eb0-499f-ba64-25e436f04c4b",
      "name": "name_3"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my django method

```py
def get_titles():
    url = 'http://localhost:8080/titles/' 
    r = requests.get(url)
    titles = r.json()
    print(titles['data'])
```

What I need is convert the JSON into an instance of the model and pass it to the template. Please let me know how to convert JSON to Model.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Using JSON in Django templates

You don't *have* to convert the JSON structure into a Django model just to use it in a Django template: JSON structures (Python dicts) work just fine in a Django template

e.g. if you pass in `{'titles': titles['data']}` as the context to your template, you can use it as:

```
{% for title in titles %}
    ID is {{title.id}}, and name is {{title.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

As long as you don't need to store the data with Django, the above solution works just fine. If you want to store, read below.

### Make a model

You can create a model to store that JSON data in. Once stored you can pass the queryset to your template

```
class Title(models.Model)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

or use an `UUIDField`

```
class Title(models.Model)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**Store the data in a Django model**

```
# Read the JSON
titles = r.json()
# Create a Django model object for each object in the JSON 
for title in titles['data']:
    Title.objects.create(id=title['id'], name=title['name'])
```

**Use stored data to pass as template context**

```
# Then pass this dict below as the template context
context = {'titles': Title.objects.all()}
```

Comment: Thanks you'r comment. I've an question. I didn't config the database. It just consume REST service. How do I create object and get all objects that context?

Comment: Put the `Title` model I described in my answer, in a file inside your Django app called `models.py`, add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`, run database migration to create the SQL tables etc, more on that here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid to say I'm not going to create any database for my application. It's consuming REST API and convert json to Model(or Object) and send to the view templates. How do I create Model(or Object) without a db table?

Comment: If want a model without a DB table, then you don't really need a model in the Django sense :) You are fine with the JSON/Python dict in the first paragraph of the answer. Try create a view, and a template e.g. titles.html  and just pass in the JSON data you have. Post another question if you get stuck I'll help if I see it!

Comment: If you're thinking about "Model" in MVC pattern, in Django it's not required to be a Django ORM Model, it can be a Python object, Python dict (e.g. JSON). You don't _need_ a Django model to pass data to the template.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked, either edit the question's title or edit the answer... It is misleading at best.