# Load json data list in Django models

Tags: json, django

I'm tring to convert this json list to django models. but I'm confused. How can I solve this question:
Json

```
[
  {
    "rank": 1,
    "employer": "Walmart",
    "employeesCount": 2300000,
    "medianSalary": 19177
  },
  {
    "rank": 2,
    "employer": "Amazon",
    "employeesCount": 566000,
    "medianSalary": 38466
  }
]


class Persons(models.Model):
    rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    employer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    employeesCount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    medianSalary = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    verbose_name = 'Person'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Person'
```

Comment: is this a once in a lifetime thing? if so write a script with a for loop go though every entry of the json, get the values and create an object `Persons.objects.create(rank=rank_value...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON data convert to the django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825875/json-data-convert-to-the-django-model)

Comment: Sorry can u help me I've got troubles when I convert json to django models. How it should look

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

1. You can either write some sort of script or management command and load data in the database.
2. Have you looked at the [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#loaddata) command? I am not sure if you can edit this JSON, if you can change your JSON to something like below and put it in a folder with name `fixtures` within the app and run command `python manage.py loaddata <name_of_file>` will load all of this data to the specified model

```
[
  {
    "model": "app_name.person",
    "fileds": {
       "rank": 1,
      "employer": "Walmart",
      "employeesCount": 2300000,
      "medianSalary": 19177
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "app_name.person",
    "fileds": {
      "rank": 2,
      "employer": "Amazon",
      "employeesCount": 566000,
      "medianSalary": 38466
    }
  }
]
```

I don't know if 2nd option is feasible for you but the first option would definitely work.